# what happens when we use class as return type in a mthod in c#

Tags: c#, methods

My previous question was bit unclear to many. I proceed with same question?

```
class stockData
{
   public string _stockName{get; set;}
   public int _stockId{get; set;}
   public double _currPrice{get; set;}
}

class getstockData
{
   // here actually what happens here when we use the class as return type?
   public stockData getStock(string symbol)
   {
      //any statement
      return abc;
   }
   //and what actually happening here, when we put class as parameter.
   public void getStock(stockData stockData)
   {
      //any statement
   }
}
```

In above codes there are two questions. and it is more clear than my previous one.
regards

Comment: If your previous question lacked clarity, you should edit it, not repost. Reposting is not a good idea on Stackoverflow.

Comment: The first method returns an instance of `stockData`, the second one accepts an instance of `stockData` - what exactly do you mean by "what actually happens"? How does it look like in IL? How does the stack look like?

Comment: You should edit your *previous* question until it's clear, rather than creating a new one. Note that this question still isn't really clear. What do you mean by "what happens"? It's not clear what you're confused about.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes the OP can

Comment: Thanks you all to respond me soon. thanks @Krumelur this will certainly help me. regards